# React reroute on ajax call

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have an authentication side on my application working using `passport`.
This will give me a `403` back when the user does not have access to a specific route, this includes api routes too.

i.e.

```
app.use('/api/calendar', passport, authorize([roles.SOME_ROLE]), calendar);
```

later I call this `api/calendar` route to get a calendar like so:

```
var getAll = function () {
    return $.get(routes.MAIN + routes.GET_CALENDAR)
            .error(function(error) {
                 //this is where I am stuck
            });
}
```

How do I, when I reach the error part, redirect to another route?

Note that this file is a service file, the `getAll` method gets called from the `React` component:

```
loadCalendar: function () {
            var self = this;
            calendarService.getAll()
                .then(function (data) {
                    self.props.load(data);
                });
        },
```

I know I could do it in this `loadCalendar` function but that would mean that any time I do a call to any service I need to include an `error` block and I'd prefer to have it centralized in the `service` files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for people trying to figure this one out, I found it some time ago.

first, you need to have a `Router` in your `React` component.

```
var withRouter = require('react-router').withRouter;
var SomeComponent = withRouter(
    React.createClass({
        PropTypes: {
        },
        .........
```

Next, we setup our service to be able to call the `Router`:

```
var router = null;
var setRouter = function (routerToSet) {
    router = routerToSet;
}
//..... other stuff

module.exports: {
//.....
setRouter: setRouter
}
```

Now we can call - on an `Ajax` error - the router to redirect

```
function handleErrorResponse(error, router) {
    if(error.status == statusCodes.UNAUTHORIZED) {
        if(router) {
            router.replace(unauthorizedPath);
        }
        else {
            toastr.error("Router not defined", "CRITICAL ERROR");
            throw new Exception("CRITICAL ERROR: Router not defined");             
        }
    }
    else {
        return error; 
    }
}


function handleError(error) {
    return handleErrorResponse(error, router);
}

var myAjaxCallToHandle= function () {    
    return $.ajax({
        url: routes.where_ever,
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        method: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json"
    })
    .error(handleError);
}
```

The only thing left to do is, in the component, couple the `Router`

```
//.........
        getInitialState: function () {
            unitPlantService.setRouter(this.props.router);
        }
//.........
```